# URL Rewrite to different port based on condition

Tags: iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I have a site that is something like this:

```
https://www.website.org/cms
```

I have an application that's running on another service on the same server on a different port that I want to have accessible over this URL:

```
https://www.website.org/dashboard
```

the dashboard site is accessible from the server using `http://localhost:8081/dashboard`

How can I use URL Rewrite to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So simple actually:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="dashboard">
         <match url="(dashboard.+)" />
         <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8081/{R:0}" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Where did you put the rule? At machine (host) level or on the website level (at a level wehre website.org is bound)? Does it also work from requests on the same machine?